# There is an error at line 1 of your code. Check the node with id Agama-start-Flow : Learning Agama Lab for Gluu policy modification

Tags: identity-management, gluu

I am creating the basic authentication policy by referring below link.
https://agama-lab.gluu.org/quick-start-guide/

I don't know why I am getting line 1 error even though I haven't added anything to it in the top node which is start.

[image: The overview of my node , the top node showing error]

[image: inside the top node]